# Android - Set background view for whole app dynamically

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, colors

I set the background color of my app with this code:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

How could I have this carry over to the next activities that come after this one, without using XML because it is not always the color RED. This depends on a selection by the user. But once the user has selected RED I want this color to carry over to the next activities. Is there a way to go about this without doing something like this for all the actives.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Color", "RED");
startActivity(intent);
```

And then on the next activity use that Extra to set the color. Is there a way that I can just set it for all the following activities until the user changes it?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Either store in Shared Preferences or take one global static variable for background color and use it any where in app.

Comment: @HareshChhelana where is Shared Preferences

Comment: Check : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

### colors used in android are of `int` format not `String`

`setBackgroundColor() takes a color in numeric form (e.g., 0xFFFF0000 for red)`

---

So you can do this way:

Suppose from `class A` sending a int variable to `class B`

```
int bgColor=Color.RED; <---Change It with whatever you want(but should be numeric)

Intent bgIntent = new Intent(Background.this, MainScreen.class);
bgIntent.putExtra("background",  bgColor);
startActivity(bgIntent);
```

and on class B

```
Intent bgIntent = getIntent();
bgGlobal = bgIntent.getExtras().getInt("background",-1);

if(bgGlobal != -1) 
{
   DetailsLayout.setBackgroundResource(Color.parseColor(bgGlobal));
}
else 
{
   DetailsLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.a1);
}
```

for more info please refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int))

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to get #Code for that color and use

To send value

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Color", "#Code");
startActivity(intent);
```

In next activity..

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(intent.getExtra("Color")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the setting of background color in a singleton class, say

```
public class ColorHolder {
    public static ColorHolder instance=null;
    private int color;
    public static ColorHolder getInstance(){
        if(instance==null){
            instance=new ColorHolder();
        }
    }
    public int getColor(){
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(int c){
        color=c;
    }
}
```

Then create a subclass of Activity, say

```
public class ColoredActivity extends Activity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle s){
        super.onCreate(s);
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
        rl.setBackgroundColor(ColorHolder().getInstance().getColor());
    }
}
```

Then all the Activities which want to apply this setting should extend this "ColoredActivity"